# How much do R2-D2 and BB-8 weigh?

Tags: star-wars, droids

The question is self-explanatory:  How much do the astromech droids R2-D2 and BB-8 weigh, in-universe?

Comment: I was thinking of this myself rewatching ESB. Threepio and Artoo fall from a short height from a hovercraft into the sand, yet manage to get almost completely buried. That's some impact!

Comment: @CreationEdge that was in RotJ :)

Comment: @RedCaio Geez, and I almost typed Ep XI instead. I don't know why I mixed up the titles, I hadn't even started drinking yet!

Comment: @CreationEdge - as we see in Ep7, there is quicksand on sand planets in TGFFA. Could have possibly been that? (ok, ok, I know it was Lucas doing his Kurosawa thing. But I'm allowed to my own fan theories, ain't i?)

Comment: @DVK I think comedy relief gets a free pass. Comedy is the power that bends the universe to its will.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Mark Twain is a Sith Lord?

Answer (score 2):

### R2-D2:

- Wookieepedia says (citing "Star Wars Rebels: Head to Head") 32 kg.
- Apparently the same number was in EU/Legends, in "Star Wars: Head-to-Head Tag Teams, pg 50" as per the same page.

### BB-8

- couldn't find in-universe evidence in the film, novelization, or Visual Dictionary page.
- Sphero's out of universe popular toy is ~200 g (at the height of 11cm, compared to real one's Databank height of 0.67m). If we proportionally size the weight up by 6^3=216 times, we get **~42kg**.

  Which probably isn't accurate, since I assume TGFFA has much better/lighter materials than Sphero (since R2-D2 could fly and BB-8 has liquid metal cables that hold its weight and pull him up).
- Doing very back of the envelope guessing it looks like his body is ~20-30% of R2-D2 by volume. (they fit in same size X-Wing astromech socket.

  - R2-D2's body seems to be exactly 1.5 times BB-8 body, since his body+head fits exactly 2 BB-8 bodies and his head is an exact hemisphere of the same radius. That gives us 9.42+4.19/2=**11.5** for R2-D2 volume given radius of 1 (for simplicity of comparison), excluding appendages. BB-8 is 4.19 for the body and roughly 0.26 for head (half a sphere size of half the body), totalling **4.45**.

  Assuming he's not made of some advanced ultralight composites that severely affected his density by comparison the above gives us **~12.4kg**. It may be less because of more advanced materials, or because I didn't count the volume of R2-D2's legs; or it can be less because I assume a spherical droid's internal space has less empty lacunae due to better space packing. Without better canon info, I'll call those factors a wash for hand-waved calculation purposes and settle on **12kg**.

  [image]

Comment: Finn needs to hit the gym if he struggles with 12kgs

Comment: @CandiedMango - huh? when was he carrying BB-8? I know it FELL on him... but I wouldn't be happy if 12kg fell on me either :)

Comment: Before it falls on him he attempts to lift BB-8 down into the hold. He makes a sort of struggling gasp and falls over being crushed by BB-8. 12kgs is really not a lot at all specially for a storm trooper who has probably had some form of fitness training :P

Comment: @CandiedMango - I must have mis-seen it. I was under firm impression that Rey dropped BB-8 on him from above. Can't wait for DVD!

Comment: Hmm I seem to remember him rolling off the edge into an expecting finn. Knowing modern times we'll only have to wait a few months!

Comment: @CandiedMango  As a trained stormtrooper, Finn is used to wearing protective armour!

Comment: @MrLister - clearly not, **since he takes off the bloody helmet the moment he can, contrary to regulations** :)

Comment: According to TFA: Head-to-Head, BB-8 weighs 18Kg